# React useEffect on function props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just started using React function hooks. I was looking into a case where you have a parent function which passes an array and a child function which relies on the array contents.

App.js (parent) ->

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import ChartWrapper from './StaticChart/ChartWrapper';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  let data = [];

  function newVal() {
    let obj = null;
    let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    let timeNow = Date.now();
    obj = {'time': timeNow, 'value': val};
    data.push(obj);
   // console.log(obj);
  }

  useEffect(
    () => {
      setInterval(() => {newVal();}, 500);
    }, []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChartWrapper data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ChartWrapper.js (child) ->

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
export default function ChartWrapper(props) {

    const svgRef = useRef();
    const navRef = useRef();

    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log('function called');
        }, [props.data]        
    );

    return (
        <div>
            <svg ref = {svgRef} width = {700} height = {400}></svg>
            <svg ref = {navRef} width = {700} height = {75}></svg>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So every time App.js adds a new object in the array, ChartWrapper gets called. Currently, in the ChartWrapper function, I have useEffect which should listen to changes in props.data array and get executed, but it is not working. The only time the function gets called is initially when the component renders.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Javascript passes arrays by reference. Even when you push a new value onto it, it's still the same array. useEffect doesn't do deep comparison (i.e. it doesn't compare the contents of the array).

Comment: If instead of passing props.data to your useEffect dependency array, try passing `[JSON.stringify(props.data)]` and see if it works the way you want. Btw, that probably isn't a great solution, just a way of illustrating what's going on.

Comment: Can you try to copy the array into a new array, rather than mutate it? i.e. replace `data.push(obj)` with `data = [...data, obj]`

Comment: @ChristianFosli That could potentially cause `useEffect` to re-run on every render, since the array will always be different.

Comment: We're only changing `data` every 500ms, right? I presume we want `useEffect` to run every time `data` changes.

Comment: I mean it would re-run on every _render_, even if data didn't change. However, since spread doesn't actually clone objects, your solution could potentially work.

Comment: @Cully I understand what you mean, I also tried doing [props.data.length] instead of [props.data] only. That also didn't work. Shouldn't that be working since the length of the array should change?

Comment: @ps1234 Yeah, that should work (though also not a great solution, since you can modify the array while maintaining the same length). Could you create a codepen/jsfiddle example or something that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: @ChristianFosli 500 is just an arbitrary number. In use I cant guarantee if it will be after a specific duration always.

Comment: @ps1234 that's fine, we're not relying on that number. I was just trying to understand the problem Cully highlighted.

Comment: I agree with @ChristianFosli here, create a new array when the contents change will trigger the useEffect on the child. it will not cause it to re-run on every render but only when the value gets re-defined

Comment: Thanks guys, will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I ran your code and figured out what the problem is. `data` is changing, but it isn't triggering a re-render of `ChartWrapper`. So your `useEffect` in `ChartWrapper` is only run once (on the initial render). In order to trigger a re-render, you'll need to create and update `data` using `useState`:

```js
let [data, setData] = useState([])

function newVal() {
    let obj = null;
    let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    let timeNow = Date.now();
    obj = {'time': timeNow, 'value': val};
    const newData = [...data]
    newData.push(obj)
    setData(newData)
}
```

However, that isn't quite enough. Since your `setInterval` function is defined once, the value of `data` in its call context will always be the initial value of `data` (i.e. and empty array). You can see this by doing `console.log(data)` in your `newVal` function. To fix this, you could add `data` as a dependency to that `useEffect` as well:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(newVal, 1000);
}, [data]);
```

But then you'll create a new `setInterval` every time data changes; you'll end up with many of them running at once. You could clean up the setInterval by returning a function from `useEffect` that will `clearInterval` it:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(newVal, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [data]);
```

But at that point, you might as well use `setTimeout` instead:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(newVal, 1000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
}, [data]);
```

This will cause a new `setTimeout` to be created every time `data` is changed, so it will run just like your `setInterval`.

Anyway, your code would look something like this:

```js
const ChartWrapper = (props) => {
    useEffect(
        () => {
            console.log('function called');
        }, [props.data]        
    );

    return <p>asdf</p>
}

const App = () => {
  let [data, setData] = useState([])

  function newVal() {
    let obj = null;
    let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    let timeNow = Date.now();
    obj = {'time': timeNow, 'value': val};
    const newData = [...data]
    newData.push(obj)
    setData(newData)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(newVal, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, [data]);

  return (
     <ChartWrapper data={data} />
  )
}
```

And a running example: https://jsfiddle.net/kjypx0m7/3/

Something to note is that this runs fine with the ChartWrapper's `useEffect` dependency just being `[props.data]`. This is because when `setData` is called, it is always passed a new array. So `props.data` is actually different when ChartWrapper re-renders.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in hooks' dependencies are compared by reference. Since arrays are objects as well, when you say `data.push` the reference to the array does not change and, therefore, the hook is not triggered.

Primitive values, on the other hand, are compared by value. Since `data.length` is a primitive type (`number`), for your purpose, putting the dependency on `data.length` instead would do the trick.

However, if you were not modifying the array's length, only the values inside of it, the easiest way to trigger a reference difference (as explained in the first paragraph) would be to wrap up this array in a `setState` hook.

Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-murdock-qlto0. Changing the dependency in the Child component from `[data.length]` to `[data]` has no difference.